# SharePoint 2013 Activity Event in Newsfeed

Tags: 2013, development, newsfeed, activity-feed

I need to add custom notifications to the personal Newsfeed on people's MySites. I found several tutorials and code examples for SharePoint 2010 on the net and tried to do the same with SharePoint 2013. They're all about creating `ActivityEvents` with the `ActivityManager`.

Here's the C# code I tried:

```
        var targetSite = new SPSite("URL to MySite webapp");
        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(targetSite);
        var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

        var ownerProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\user1");
        var publisherProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\user2");

        var activityManager = new ActivityManager(ownerProfile, context);

        Entity publisher = new MinimalPerson(publisherProfile).CreateEntity(activityManager);
        Entity owner = new MinimalPerson(ownerProfile).CreateEntity(activityManager);
        ActivityEvent activityEvent = ActivityEvent.CreateActivityEvent(activityManager, 17, owner, publisher);
        activityEvent.Name = "StatusMessage";
        activityEvent.ItemPrivacy = (int)Privacy.Public;
        activityEvent.Owner = owner;
        activityEvent.Publisher = publisher;
        activityEvent.Value = "HELLOOOO";
        activityEvent.Commit();

        ActivityFeedGatherer.BatchWriteActivityEvents(new List<ActivityEvent> { activityEvent }, 0, 1);
```

The Id `17` in the `CreateActivityEvent` function is for the `StatusMessage` activity type, which is layouted like `{Publisher} says: {Value}` in the ressource files, so I provide the `Value` property of my `ActivityEvent`.

The code runs without any exception and in the `User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB` database I can see the right entries appear in the `ActivityEventsConsolidated` table.
But the activity is not visible in the activity feed, neither on the Owner's one, nor on the Publisher's one, even though these people follow each other. I ran the Activity Feed Job in the CA manually to update the activity feed.
Also, I tried to do the same with custom `ActivityTypes` with own ressource files, same result: The entry in the `ActivityEventsConsolidated` table (or `ActivityEventsPublished` if Owner=Publisher) appear, but no entries on the MySite.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem myself.
In `Central Administration`, `Setup MySites`, you have to enable the `Enable SharePoint 2010 activity migration` setting in the `Newsfeed` section in order to support SP1010 legacy activities in SP2013.